# Do Parse queries run one after the other or simultaneously when retrieving objects?

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I have two queries in my activity and was wondering if they are executed one after the other or concurrently, since the 2nd query is returning an empty list. In my first query, I'm retrieving the ParseObject using the objectId and then setting it to a class variable. In my second query, I use that ParseObject that I set to find all objects in the "Answers" class ("Question" is a pointer to an object in the Question" class). However, it appears that the 2nd query has already started such that it returns an empty list of objects since the ParseObject in the 1st query was not set yet. How do I go about making the queries run one after the other so the variables are set first? Or is there another approach to this problem?

```
  ParseObject question;
  ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Question");
        query.getInBackground(questionId, new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
            if(e==null){
                question = object;            
            } else {
                System.out.println(e);
            }

        }
    });


ParseQuery<ParseObject> answerQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("Answers");
    answerQuery.whereEqualTo("Question", question);
    answerQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> answers, ParseException e) {
            if(e==null){


            } else {
                System.out.println(e);
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: it is not relevant to know if they run simultaneously or not. the `getInBackground` method does exactly what it says, it does things in background. which means that the request is enqueued somewhere, will be resolved at some point, and your callback will be called someday. Now, the thing is that both your calls and your callback happen on the same thread. Which means that no matter what happens, your callback cannot happen until you release the current thread, which happens at the end of the system-called method. Which means your `question` object can never be set when you use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that is done in a background thread. You need to make the `answerQuery` lookup dependent on the completion of the `question` lookup. You can create another method to do the answer lookup like below.

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Question");
query.getInBackground(questionId, new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
    @Override
    public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
        if(e==null){
            queryAnswers(object);
        } else {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

    }
});

private void queryAnswers(ParseObject question) {
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> answerQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("Answers");
    answerQuery.whereEqualTo("Question", question);
    answerQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> answers, ParseException e) {
            if(e==null){
                // do what you want with the answers...
            } else {
                System.out.println(e);
            }

        }
    });
}
```